# Unable to login into a website with a python script?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

Hi I'm quite the python newbie. I'm currently trying to write a python script that logs into a website for me, and then opens up another page. But it doesn't work.

```
import requests
from requests import session

payload = {'username': 'xxx@gmail.com', 'password': 'xxxx'}
url = 'https://login.opendns.com'

with session() as c:
    c.post(url, data=payload)
    response = c.get('https://dashboard.opendns.com/stats/all/topdomains/today/')
    print(response.headers)
    print(response.text)
```

Can someone please help? I get these errors:
"InsecurePlatformWarning"
and then gives me the html of the login page itself. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your `response` variable equal to the response of the `get` request, which is separate and different from your `post` request. Try this:

```
response = c.post(url, data=payload)
```

and comment out the line with the `c.get()` call.

If the output after that looks good, try setting up a [callback hook](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) for the `post` call.

Define this function before your `with` block:

```
def get_today(*args, **kwargs):
    response = c.get('https://dashboard.opendns.com/stats/all/topdomains/today/')
    print response.text
```

Then change your `post` call to this:

```
response = c.post(url, data=payload, hooks=dict(response=get_today))
```